# How to delete a directory in windows %appdata%(or %programdata%) using NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis, appdata

I am building a setup using NSIS. In my setup, i need to delete a folder (and its contents) in the windows `%appdata%` (or `%programdata%` in win7) on uninstallation of my application.

As i am relatively new to NSIS, Kindly Requesting you for a Function or a piece of script that i can use in my setup to execute this operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For local user only:

```
RMDir /r "$APPDATA\YourApp"
RMDir /r "$LOCALAPPDATA\YourApp"
```

For all users:

```
SetShellVarContext all
RMDir /r "$APPDATA\YourApp"
RMDir /r "$LOCALAPPDATA\YourApp"
SetShellVarContext current
```

- Option `/r` - required to delete subfolders.
- Option `/REBOOTOK` - required for delayed removal (after system restart).

To delete files only use:

```
Delete   "$APPDATA\YourApp\*.*"
```

Comment: @Bomzinho: don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/65088/173356)